# InfoPath Designer 2013 Toolbar not reacting

Tags: infopath

I have developed quite a few InfoPath forms in my life, but I only recently started developing with InfoPath Designer 2013 and I am coming across a very peculiar "bug" (I don't know that it's a bug for sure) indeed.

The form opens fine to design but when I change a field's name, for instance, the application stops reacting in certain areas. The InfoPath toolbar doesn't react at all except for when I click FILE (which opens up the little menu that's supposed to open when you click on the InfoPath icon in the very top left corner). In addition, I can also right-click on the elements inside the form to open some of the properties of the elements; however on the right side of the screen where the fields and groups are listed, nothing reacts either.

I have tried to find this on Google and I was quite surprised that it didn't seem like anyone else had asked about this; however that seems to be the case (although I'm hoping not). Please note that InfoPath stops reacting only after I change the field or group name.

Does anyone out there have any idea as to what might be causing this?

Thank you and regards.

Hermann

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. The only workaround I've found is to Alt-F, Save, close InfoPath, reopen InfoPath, then reopen the document.